# Using a vector of unsigned chars in a map

Tags: c++, vector, maps, unsigned-char

I need help using `unsigned char`s in `std::vector`s that are inside of a `std::map`.

This is how I declare the `std::map`:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<unsigned char>> DataMap;
```

The problem comes when I try to assign a `std::vector` to the `std::map`.

`it->first` comes from another `std::map`, as this code is inside a loop.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> charHolder;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    charHolder.push_back('2');
}

DataMap.insert(std::pair<int, std::vector<unsigned char>(it->first, charHolder));
```

The errors:

> Template argument 2 is invalid

I need to assigned a `char[]` array to the `2` place in the `std::map`. I've tried an array, but I had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `>` character

```
DataMap.insert (std::pair<int, std::vector<unsigned char>>(it->first, charHolder));
                                                         ^
```

You may use uniform initializer as following:

```
DataMap.insert ({it->first, charHolder});
```

Comment: It's always best to have someone look over your work, but unfortunately I don't have that so thanks for the help :)

Comment: Another option, especially for pre-C++11 compilers, is to use `std::make_pair()` instead and let the compiler deduce the template parameters for you: `DataMap.insert(std::make_pair(it->first, charHolder));`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good option for pre-c++11.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the many fun and varied ways to get data into a map:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<unsigned char>> DataMap;

void add(int i, std::vector<unsigned char> v)
{
    // efficient move versions
    DataMap.emplace(i, std::move(v));

    DataMap[i] = std::move(v);

    DataMap.insert(std::make_pair(i, std::move(v)));

    DataMap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, 
        std::make_tuple(i), 
        std::forward_as_tuple(std::move(v)));

    // less efficient copy versions
    DataMap.emplace(i, v);

    DataMap[i] = v;

    DataMap.insert(std::make_pair(i, v));

    DataMap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, 
        std::make_tuple(i), 
        std::make_tuple(v));

}
```